# How to get block numbers in a trace file?

Tags: parsing, filesystems, block

I am trying to analyze the performance of a f2fs file system using DiskSim. DiskSim requires block numbers as part of its input parse file.Can anyone tell me how I can actually get these block numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it can help you or not. However, hdparm --fibmap "filename" shows the LBAs of the file. As a either way, you can use 'filefrag' command.